# Let $C$ denote the union of line segments $[-1-i,2]$ and $[2,3+2i]$...

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $C$ denote the union of line segments $[-1-i,2]$ and $[2,3+2i]$.
>   Find $\int_c(z^2-z+1)dz$.

I am confused about the notation. So, is there a line joining $-1-i$ to $2$, and then a line joining $2$ to $3+2i$?

If so, then how should I find the integral? I tried:

Let $C_1$ be the line from $-1-i$ to $2$ and $C_2$ be the line joining $2$ to $3+2i$.

Then, $\int_c(z^2-z+1)dz = \int_{-1-i}^2(z^2-z+1)dz + \int_2^{3+2i}(z^2-z+1)dz=[\frac{z^3}{3}-\frac{z^2}{2}+z]^2_{-1-i} +...etc$

I did it this way because I have trouble finding a $z(t)$ where $a \le t \le b$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
The segments $[-1-i,2]$ connects $(-1,-1)$ to $(2,0)$ so you can use formula
$$\frac{y-y_1}{x-x_1}=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$$
and find parametric equation of this segment $3y=x-2$ for $-1\leq x\leq2$ and
$$z(t)=(t,\dfrac{t-2}{3})~~~~~;~~~~~-1\leq t\leq2$$

Answer (score 0):

You can parametrize every segment $[z_1,z_2]$ where $z_1,z_2\in \mathbb{C}$ the following way : 
$$z_1 t+(1-t)z_2,t\in[0,1]$$
Or more generally :
$$z_1 \left(\frac{t}{b-a}-a\right)+\left(\frac{1-t}{b-a}-a\right)z_2,t\in[a,b]$$